# WebClient StatusCode

Tags: c#, webclient, http-status-code-302

I am using WebClient to get some info from a page that is sometimes not available [302 Moved Temporarily]. So i want to program to detect whether the page exists

I tried to override the WebClient WebResponse with the following code to only return the page when it's status is OK but it did not worked.

```
protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
{
    var response = base.GetWebResponse(request);

    if (response is HttpWebResponse)
        return (response as HttpWebResponse).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ? response : null;
    return null;
}
```

when i used my overriden class to get the page (when it is unavailable) it just redirected and did not returned null

Get code

```
private async Task<string> Get(string uri)
{
    return await Handler.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(uri));
}
```

[WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE] : i want the web client tried to get the page but it was not found so it has been redirected to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't tell you the status but it can be inferred by the fact that you were redirected.

```
if(reponse.ResponseUri != request.RequestUri) {
   // if you really want to know the status
   // set AllowAutoRedirect = false;
   // and send another request in here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`WebClient` will follow redirects automatically by default (up to a maximum number).

If you override `GetWebRequest` to modify the returned `HttpWebRequest`, setting its [`AllowAutoRedirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx) property to false, then I believe it will just give you back the 302 directly - although possibly via an exception...

Comment: Is there any way to do this without setting the auto redirect property to false ?

Comment: @RuneS: Not that I know of - you don't want to follow redirects, do you?

Comment: no i want to follow redirects normally but at the same time detecting if an 302 code happened.

Comment: @RuneS: But in the question description it sounds like want to return `null` if there's a redirect. You need to edit your question to make it *much* clearer what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: yea that is what i want to do. Only returning the page if it's status code == 200 [OK]. or any other way to issue me of the redirects occured

Comment: @RuneS: Nope, I'm none the wiser. How can you return null *and* redirect? As I said before, you should edit your question to try to make this far clearer. (I'm off to bed in a minute, but I doubt that other people will be able to answer if you don't clarify the question.) Fundamentally, if you *only* want to return the response if the status code is 200, then you *don't* want to redirect, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ok what i want to do is briefly is redirect and tell me that there was 302 status